# flutter get part of strings, youtube iframe

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm beginner and i want to ask how get or search after embed "MAT3z3xtcd4" and before "

from this strings

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/MAT3z3xtcd4" width="560" height="315" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>
```

this iframe in my website under Videos Category

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a thousand ways to do this, but many of them are just simple string splitting, substringing, etc. Check the documentation for [String](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.1.0/dart-core/String-class.html).

Here's a simple, verbose example that demonstrate several of those techniques:

```
void main() {
  String s = '<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/MAT3z3xtcd4" width="560" height="315" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>';

  List<String> tags = s.replaceAll('<', ' ').replaceAll('>', ' ').split(' ');
  print(tags);

  String srcTag = tags.where((s) => s.startsWith('src=')).first;
  print (srcTag);

  String url = srcTag.substring(5, srcTag.length - 1);
  print(url);

  String suffix = url.split('/').last;
  print(suffix);
}
```

Comment: but i use: `List<String> tt2 =
      '<p><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/kOzq3EsA6bE" width="560" height="315" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe></p>'
          .split(new RegExp('\/embed\/'));`

Comment: thank you very much Richard Heap your cor is very right